# Why do we need to specify type in format specifiers in the C++ printf function?

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

I've done a bit of PHP and when you declare variables you do not need to declare the type (eg. string or int).

However I have to tweak a very simple C file and, in order to get the print function to work correctly, I have to include a type specifier for the output of each variable.

Why isn't this type automatically inferred from the variable itself?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more for us.  I can't make out what you are asking.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Don't ask questions in the question's title, or at least repeat them in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `printf` is part of the C-compatibility part of C++, where type detection wasn't so hot :-)

There is a disconnect between the specifiers in the format string and the data items being used for that specifier, for example:

```
printf ("String at memory %p is '%s'\n", mystr, mystr);
printf ("That character is '%c', ASCII code %d, hex %02x\n", mych, mych, mych);
```

If you use C++ streams for your output, this isn't so much of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

C is a very simple language, by which I mean it offers a pretty minimal abstractions over the bare metal. The basic types come with *no* type information attached and even `struct`s only get what type info *you* give them.

So in a typical implementation, when the compiler sees

```
int x, y;
float z;
int x = foo(y,z);
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` are likely one machine word which is interpreted as a 2s-complement integer for `x` and `y, and as a IEEE-754 floating-point value for z, and *nothing else*.

The the compiler does something like

- advance the stack pointer to allow room for a return value
- `push` `y` and `z` onto the stack (what order it does this in is implementation dependent)
- `push` the current `stack pointer+two instructions` as the return address
- `branch` to the entry point of `foo`.

(Decent chips provide some support to amke this easier, but still...)

Then foo

- reads `y` and `z` from their locations relative the current stack value
- does whatever on them
- writes the return to `x` (again found by offset from the stack pointer)
- `branch` back to the return address that the calling routine `push`ed.

If `foo` has not been instructed what type the passed arguments have (as in a variadac routine like `printf`) it won't know how big each argument on the stack is (actually c coerces the size of every variadac argument with a set of up-conversion rules to fix this issue), nor how to interpret it.

PHP on the other hand, provides a sophisticated abstraction over the bare machine, and can (must, in fact to do what it does) carry some identifing information around with each value it works with.

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity, why would you put the effort to write such a detailed question where the best answer was already selected a long time ago?

Answer (score -1):

The most common specifiers are:

%d/%i  is for an integer
%c     is for char 
%s  is for a string
%f  is for float/double

For example:

```
int i = 1;
char hi[6] = "Hello"
printf("%d %s", i, hi);
```

would print

```
1 Hello
```

as given above, you can refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which is /why/ do we need the type format specifiers.

Comment: @silph Uhh this answer was from 8 years ago, why did you feel the need to comment on this right now?